# A Quiz Program with JavaScript functions and conditions

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, multidimensional-array, parameters

I have some questions about the logic of a program, which is a quiz.

```
var score = 0;

var questions = [
    ["How many moons does the Earth have?", 1],
    ["How many moons does Saturn have?", 31],
    ["How many moons does Venus have?", 0]
];

for (i=0; i<questions.length; i++)
{
    askQuestion(questions[i]);
}

function askQuestion(inquiry)
{
    var answer = prompt(inquiry[0]);

    if(answer == inquiry[1]){
        alert("Correct!");
        score++;
    }else{
        alert("Sorry. The correct answer is " + question[1]);
    }
}
```

I understand the first three statements (but I will happily be stood corrected).

The first statement is initializing the declared global variable with a numeric literal of 0, since that's how the score of a quiz should start out.

The second statement creates a multidimensional array, with each item of the array having a question and a corresponding answer.

The third statement is a for loop that cycles through each question (index value) of the array declared "questions".

The fourth statement is where I am having a little trouble understanding. And I was hoping the fine folks here can lend some clarity.

Here's what I THINK I understand. Please, correct me if I am totally in left field on understanding the underlying logic. (1) The fourth statement is creating a parameter (inquiry). (2) The local variable "answer" is being declared with a value of whatever is inputted by the user through the dialog box. The argument "inquiry[0]" corresponds to each question in the array. (3) The value "inquiry[1]" corresponds to each answer.

I'm probably wrong in my conjecture. If so, please give me some clarity, because this is a head-scratcher for me.

Thanks!! :)

Comment: "*The fourth statement is creating a parameter (inquiry).*" - most importantly, the fourth statement is creating a **function** with the name `askQuestion`. That function does something (the code in the body) which uses the parameters declared.

Comment: `"The correct answer is " + question[1]` should be `"The correct answer is " + inquiry[1]`

Comment: By "*the fourth statement*", do you refer to the one that begins with `function` or do you refer to the statement in the loop body (`askQuestion(questions[i]);`)?

Comment: What was throwing me off was the nested IF statement in the fourth statement, because, at first, it looked like it was only addressing the first index value of the multidimensional array, but it can't be just addressing that index value, since the increment operator is giving a point per correct question. Am I right in that understanding?

Comment: By the fourth statement, I am referring to the function itself, not the function call in the for loop.

Comment: By the way, this quiz works the way it is. It goes through each question, giving a point (adding 1 to the value of the global variable "score" through the increment operator in the nested if statement in the function).

Comment: Inside the function, you don't know what `inquiry` is. All that can be said is that it looks like a two-element array. Only from the call `askQuestion(questions[i]);` you can see that it is passing one of the inner arrays from `questions` to the function as the `inquiry` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

So no one knows what inquiry[0] and inquiry[1] refer to?

I think inquiry[0] refers to each question and inquiry[1] refers to each answer. I just don't know for sure.

Sorry for the bump.

Thanks.